# Problem running ps to find PID with multiple users

Tags: c

When I run the following code and then run ps to see the processes running, I only get 4 ./a.out running processes even though there are 5 forks. Why is that? How am I able to see the other fork? Also, if multiple people are using my computer, running the same process a.out, how can I terminate only my processes, using only linux commands? Please help.

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
32941 ttys000    0:00.10 -bash
34098 ttys000    0:00.08 less
33651 ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
33652 ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
33654 ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
33655 ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
```

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define N 5     /* How many children to make. */
#define D 1200  /* Sleep 1200 seconds = 20 minutes */

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  pid_t p;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    p = fork();
    if (p == 0) {
      close(0);
      close(1);
      close(2);
      if (i == 2) {
        setsid();
      }
      sleep(D);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All five processes are running, but you're using the `ps` command that only shows processes associated with your session, but the `setsid()` called for i=2 sets a different session, so the default ps options won't show you.

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3048 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 8288 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 8289 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 8291 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 8292 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 8301 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

$ ps -fe | grep a.out
steve     8288     1  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out
steve     8289     1  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out
steve     8290     1  0 13:39 ?        00:00:00 ./a.out  <-- missing one
steve     8291     1  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out
steve     8292     1  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 ./a.out
steve     8303  3048  0 13:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto a.out
$
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ps` only displays processes with the same session id as itself and associated with a terminal. When you changed the session id of one of the processes, you disqualified it from being listed. `ps x` will include all of your processes.

By default, `ps` only lists the processes belong to you. You can be sure of this by using `ps ux` to include the owners of the processes in the output.

You can use the `kill` utility to kill these processes. Unless you are root, you can't kill other processes owned by others even if you tried.